# How can I get list of all types from graphql schema?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

On client I get schema by [introspectSchema](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/remote-schemas.html).

In my app I want to get list of all types which we have in schema, but parse existing object is very hard task.

Is there some good way to do it?

Answer (score 9):

GraphQL has powerful introspection capabilities built in. To get the names of the types in your schema you can run this GraphQL query:

```
{
  __schema {
    types {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

You can read more about introspection in GraphQL here:

https://graphql.org/learn/introspection/